# Eclipse Download file "Not a valid archive"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I downloaded eclipse for PHP (Helios win 32) from eclipse site but when I try to open the downloaded file it says "Zip file is not a valid archive"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
H.P.

Comment: Which file (the exact name)? Try to open it with what?

Comment: File name eclipse-php-helios-win32.Zip and try to open with WinZip

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your download is simply corrupted. You can obtain the checksums for the downloads at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr (in the column on the right) to compare against what you've downloaded.

Comment: seems like a problem with every download, i finally downloaded JUNO and added php plugin to get the work done